# Foreign key belongsTo selectBox

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a table product :

- id
- name
- date_operation
- category_id (foreign key form table category)

Table category:

- id
- name
- description

In the addProduct view I would like to display a select box that contains categories from the category table:

But i have this error

> Undefined variable: categories (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Blg\resources\views\addProduct.blade.php)

**addProduct.balde.php**

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <input type="text" name ="name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="">
        </div>
     </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="textArea" class="col-lg-2 control-label">categorie</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
         @foreach($categories as $categorie)
           <option value="{{ $categorie->id }}">{{ $categorie->name }}</option>
         @endforeach
       </div>
   </div>
```

**CreatesController.php**

```
public function add(Request $request)
        {
            $categories = Categories::all();
            $products = new Product;
            $products->name = $request->input('name'); 
            $products->date_operation = $request->input('date_operation'); 
            $products->category_id = $request->input('category_id'); 
            $products->save(); 
            return view('addProdcut', ['categories' => $categories]);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you structure is not correctly.

your method must be that

```
public function create() {

   $categories = Categories::all();

   return view('addProdcut', ['categories' => $categories]);
}



public function add(Request $request)
        {

            $products = new Product;
            $products->name = $request->input('name'); 
            $products->date_operation = $request->input('date_operation'); 
            $products->category_id = $request->input('category_id'); 
            $products->save(); 
            return redirect('some page')->withMessage('your product has been added');

        }
```